# Javascript - execute a function based on a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the following function with 2 input instances (name='Password', name='Email') depending on the name specified in the input element 'name' property (either 'Password' or 'Email), based on that I'd like to execute a relevant function (setPassword() or setEmail). I could just do it as follows but, I'm sure there'll be a more elegant/clever way of doing it.

```
const handleChange = event => {
        const { value, name } = event.target;

        if (name === 'Password') {
            setPassword(value);
        }
        
        if (name === 'Email' ) {
            setEmail(value);
        }

}
```

I'm probably after something like that:

```
   `set${name}(${value})`
```

Is executing something like that possible? If so, would it still be good practice or I should stick with a verbose but clear 'if' statements above?

Comment: `switch(name)` would be one "good" way. A map of `{Password: setPassword, ...}` to identify the function as a whitelist could work too. But don't allow arbitrary calls.

Answer (score 0):

### Approach 1

If you are looking for elegance, you can use a shorthand if statement like this:

```js
const handleChange = event => {
  const { value, name } = event.target;
      
  name === 'Password' && setPassword(value);
  name === 'Email' && setEmail(value);
}
```

### Approach 2

If you would like to have more of a dynamic approach, you could create an object that contains your functions this way the inputs can't execute functions that do something that you defined but was never supposed to run.

```js
// This should only contain methods that you allow to run dynamically

class InputWrapper {
  setPassword() {
    // Sets the password
  }
  setEmail() {
    // Sets the email
  }
}
```

next we can handle this by creating an instance of the above class. This way we don't run functions outside of the class. if the function inside the class doesn't exist nothing gets executed.

```js
const handleChange = event => {
  try {
    const { value, name } = event.target;
    const handler = new InputWrapper();
    handler[`set${name}`](value);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option of doing this

```
    // Set your app in object
    const App = {
      password: setPassword,
      email: setEmail
    };

    const handleChange = event => {
      const { value, name } = event.target;
      // Call your app methods, if it exists
      if(App[name]) App[name](value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think creating mappings is good ways to replace if statements

```
const mappings = {
  Password: setPassword
  Email: setEmail
}

mappings[name](value)
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "module pattern" to wrap your functions, and then call your function by assembling the string within square brackets.  Something like this:

```
function doSomething() {
   var setPassword = function(input) {
       console.log("setPassword", input);
   };
   var setUsername = function(input) {
       console.log("setUsername", input);
   };
   
   return {
       "setPassword": setPassword,
       "setUsername": setUsername
   }
}

function handleChange(whichProperty) {
   var myFunc = doSomething();
   myFunc['set'+whichProperty]("hello");
}
```

Note how I can assemble the function name here: `myFunc['set'+whichProperty]("hello");`

I wrote up an example here for you to see it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/0nc8f7oa/